# Quebra de linha no message do <p:confirm> Primefaces

Tags: java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Não estou conseguindo implementar a quebra de linha no código a seguir:

`<p:confirm icon="ui-icon-alert" header="Confirma a alteração do Status" 
    message="Tem certeza que deseja alterar a Situação do Candidato? O reenvio no    período de 6 meses poderá haver uma nova cobranca!">
</p:confirm>`

Preciso que o texto que está após a interrogação seja exibido na linha de baixo. 
Já tentei usar `\n` e não funcionou. Não é permitido usar `<br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

```
<p:confirm icon="ui-icon-alert" header="Confirma a alteração do Status"/>

<p:confirmDialog header="Confirmação">
    <f:facet name="message">
        <p:outputText value="Tem certeza que deseja alterar a Situação do Candidato?"/><br/>
        <p:outputText value="O reenvio no período de 6 meses poderá haver uma nova cobranca!"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Rafael, isoladamente funciona (apenas trocar a tag lib <p:outputText> para <h:outputText>, mas no meu caso eu uso um `<p:confirmDialog>` global. Mas valeu, pois funciona mas ainda não é a solução.